# Максимально эффективно десериализовать объект

Tags: c#, .net, синтаксический-анализ

Доброго времени суток!
У меня появилась проблема. Требуется создать объекты следующих классов. (показываю только поле)

```
public class MyClass
{
   private List<AnotherClass> nice_name;
}
public class AnotherClass
{
   private int field_int;
   private string field_string;
   private List<DeepChildClass> deep_child;
}
```

Также есть текстовый файл, где текст выглядит таким образом:

```
tag={
  child_tag={
   field_int=15
   field_string="some string"
   deep_child={
   }
   deep_child={
   }
  }
  child_tag{
   field_int=10
   field_string="another string"
   deep_child={
   }
  }
  child_tag{
   field_int=37
   field_string="different line"
   deep_child={
   }
   deep_child={
   }
   deep_child={
   }
   deep_child={
   }
  }
}
```

Как-то так. Требуется десериализовать объект максимально эффективно, так как строк в файле очень много.

1. Каким образом искать последнюю закрывающуюся скобку верхнего уровня? Повторюсь верхних тегов (tag) может быть много и они по-разному называются.
2. Использовать ли рекурсию для десериализации вложенных данных?
3. В правильном ли направлении я копаю, согласно вопросам выше? :)

Comment: Что означает «максимально эффективно»? Чем Вас не устраивает встроенная XML-сериализация?

---
Если вы пользуетесь кастомным форматом для сериализации, вам придётся писать для него кастомный парсер. Не изобретаете ли вы велосипед?

Comment: Вот я и думал об этом. Только не понимаю как настроить самодельный парсер.

Comment: @Freezze: подождите. Входной формат фиксирован? Если нет, перейдите на XML и воспользуйтесь встроенной сериализацией.

Comment: Входной формат - фиксирован. Более того, после обработки должен получиться такой же файл с новыми данными. Это говорит о том, что потребуется последующая сериализация.

Если взглянуть на пример, то теги "tag" неизменные,"child_tag" - разные (это и есть список грубо говоря), а "deep_tag" снова неизменные и их состав зависит от тега верхнего уровня.

Comment: А почему используется именно такой формат текста для сериализации, чем не устроил `JSON` ,`XML` или я не понимаю что-то?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваша грамматика довольно простая, давайте-ка напишем для неё recursive descent parser.

1) Вам нужен токенизатор.

Определяем классы токенов:

```
delegate Token StateHandler(char c);

public class Token {}
public class Ident : Token { public string Name; }
public class OpenCurly : Token {}
public class CloseCurly : Token {}
public class Equals : Token {}
public class StringLiteral : Token { public string Value; }
public class NumberLiteral : Token { public int Value; }
internal class Reparse : Token { public Token RealToken; }
```

... и пишем парсер потока (код большой, но простой):

```
StateHandler HandlerInCurrentState = NormalHandler;
IEnumerable<Token> GetTokens(IEnumerable<char> characters)
{
    foreach (var c in characters)
    {
        bool reparse = false;
        do
        {
            Token token = HandlerInCurrentState(c);
            reparse = (token is Reparse);
            if (reparse) token = ((Reparse)token).RealToken;

            if (token != null)
                yield return token;
        }
        while (reparse);
    }
}

StringBuilder accumulatedString = new StringBuilder();
Token NormalHandler(char c)
{
    if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (char.IsLetter(c) || c == '_') // ident
    {
        accumulatedString.Add(c);
        HandlerInCurrentState = IdentHandler;
        return null;
    }

    switch (c)
    {
    case '{': return new OpenCurly();
    case '}': return new CloseCurly();
    case '=': return new Equals();
    case '"':
        HandlerInCurrentState = StringHandler;
        return null;
    case '\'':
        HandlerInCurrentState = CharHandler;
        return null;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentException(
          string.Format("Unexpected input character: {0} (code: {1})", c, (int)c));
    }
}

Token IdentHandler(char c)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsDigit(c) || c == '_')
    {
        accumulatedString.Add(c);
        return null;
    }
    else // ident is finished
    {
        Token result = new StringLiteral() { Value = accumulatedString.ToString() }
        accumulatedString.Clear();
        HandlerInCurrentState = NormalHandler;
        return new Reparse() { RealToken = result; }
    }
}

bool stringEscape = false;
Token StringHandler(char c)
{
    if (!stringEscape)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case '"':
            Token result = new StringLiteral() { Value = accumulatedString.ToString() };
            accumulatedString.Clear();
            HandlerInCurrentState = NormalHandler;
            return result;
        case '\\':
            stringEscape = true;
            return null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        stringEscape = false;
        switch (c)
        {
        case '"':
        case '\\':
            break;
        case 'n':
            c = '\n';
            break;
        case 't':
            c = '\t';
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                "Unexpected escaped character: {0} (code {1})", c, (int)c));
        }
    }
    accumulatedString.Add(c);
    return null;
}
```

2) Отлично, теперь нам нужен сам парсер.

Общая часть:

```
abstract class GenericParser<T> where T: new
{
    public GenericParser(IEnumerator<Token> tokens)
    {
        this.tokens = tokens;
    }

    protected IEnumerator<Token> tokens;
    protected T result = new T();

    void MoveNext()
    {
        if (!tokens.MoveNext())
            throw new SyntaxError("unexpected end of stream");
    }

    void Ensure<T>() where T: Token
    {
        if (tokens.Current is T)
            return;
        throw new SyntaxError(
            string.Format("unexpected token type {0}, expect {1}",
                      t.GetType(), typeof(T));
    }

    protected string GetIdent()
    {
        Ensure<Ident>();
        return ((Ident)tokens.Current).Name;
    }

    protected int GetNumber()
    {
        Ensure<NumberLiteral>();
        return ((NumberLiteral)tokens.Current).Value;
    }

    public T ParseClass()
    {
        MoveNext();
        Ensure<OpenCurly>();

        while (true)
        {
            MoveNext();
            Ident id = tokens.Current as Ident;
            if (id == null) break;
            MoveNext();
            Ensure<Equals>();
            ParseValue(id.Name);
        }
        Ensure<CloseCurly>();
        return result;
    }

    protected abstract void ParseValue(string id);
}
```

... и конкретные имплементации:

```
public AnotherClassParser : GenericParser<AnotherClass>
{
    public AnotherClassParser(IEnumerator<Token> tokens) : base(tokens)
    {
        result.deep_child = new List<DeepChildClass>();
    }

    protected override void ParseValue(string id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
        case "field_int":
            MoveNext();
            result.field_int = GetNumber();
            break;
        case "field_string":
            MoveNext();
            result.field_string = GetString();
            break;
        case "deep_child":
            MoveNext();
            result.deep_child.Add(new DeepChildClassParser(tokens).ParseClass());
            break;
        default:
            throw new SyntaxError(string.Format("Unknown child name: {0}", id));
        }
    }
}
```

Всё!

Пользоваться так:

```
// получить поток символов
IEnumerable<char> characterStream = ...;
IEnumerable<Token> tokens = GetTokens(characterStream);
using (var enumerator = tokens.GetEnumerator())
{
    return new OuterClassParser(enumerator).ParseClass();
}
```